# USA immigration JFK or Seattle?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, new-york-city, jfk, delta-air-lines

I am an Indian living in Belgium. I am travelling to Seattle via New York JFK airport from Brussels. I am travelling with Delta for both the legs. I have 4 hours(3hr 54min) of stopover time at JFK.
My question is can I do my immigration at seattle international airport instead of JFK. I have heard stories of very long queues at JFK for immigration from my colleagues and I am afraid that I will miss my connecting to Seattle if I have to do my immigration at JFK. One more thing, as per my preliminary itinerary my BRU->JFK flight will arrive at terminal 4 and my JFK->SEA flight will depart from terminal 2 of JFK, how can I transfer quickly from terminal 4 to terminal 2.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** USA immigration and customs is always at your first stop in the USA, except if you are departing from an airport with [pre-clearance](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance). Brussels is not one of those.

The JFK terminals are connected by a [train](http://www.travelnerd.com/airports/jfk-airport-JFK/terminal-map).

Comment: In addition I don't believe you can even transit through the US without going through US immigration and customs.

Comment: Doing some more Google, there may be an *airside* shuttle bus between Terminals 2 and 4, and that would be *much* better than exiting past security and taking the Airtrain.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus but he will have to go through security again anyway because of the requirement to clear immigration and customs in terminal 4.

Comment: @phoog Why? At least at some USA terminals, after immigrations and customs there are transfers to domestic flights without going out of the secure zone.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: are you claiming that there are airports in the USA where you can take a flight without having gone through security in either US or Canadian soil? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @MartinArgerami You're right, they have to go through TSA at some point. What confused me was that at IAD, you may not have to go through the screening at the Main Terminal; there is also screening at the C Terminal (probably only usable if your flights are on the airlines that use it).

Comment: @MartinArgerami You can do that in Seattle. There is no security check after you clear immigration in Terminal S and you have access to all other terminals.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus arriving international travelers at JFK go directly to passport control, then through baggage claim and customs. The customs exit drops you in the arrivals meeting area, outside the TSA-secured area.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I'm surprised to read about that, because it contradicts what the  [Seattle airport's site](http://www.portseattle.org/sea-tac/passenger-services/pages/international-travel.aspx) says: "International flights arrive at the South Satellite. Passengers first clear Passport Control and then pick up their checked luggage and proceed to Customs and Border Protection (CBP). Passengers then can recheck their bags and either **proceed through security screening for connecting flights**, or transport via subway to the Main Terminal Baggage Claim to collect their bags." (bolded mine).

Comment: The OP's flight is arriving from JFK. This is not an "international flight."